# creating a trigger to lock and unlock a record

Tags: mysql, triggers, locking, record

I am creating a php script for a MySQL database whereby I call a MySQL trigger..

The trigger should affect a table which is effectively an invoice:

So when I update a field called 'date_invoiced' from its NULL default to a valid date it then  
 locks the whole record from being updated unless you have permission via your MySQL logon  
 to change it back to its default NULL, (effectively 're-opening' the invoice)  
  
No idea how to do this, any help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Adding triggers is essential for the development of complex MySQL databases that retain enforced referential integrity. Foreign keys cannot handle complex cases that perhaps involve more than one column (such as an item_id and item_type_id scenario).

**SUPER** is required when creating or dropping trigger only when binary logging is turned on.

The reason appears to be related to replication issues (MySQL 5.0 documentation).

[RTM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-triggers.html).and [RTM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html)

Read this [link](http://forums.cpanel.net/f334/mysql-5-view-trigger-permissions-case-17834-a-73842.html) to ... & this threads [Applying column permissions for a table over a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11331562/applying-column-permissions-for-a-table-over-a-trigger) , [Can't create MySQL trigger with TRIGGER privilege on 5.1.32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1627383/cant-create-mysql-trigger-with-trigger-privilege-on-5-1-32)

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a lock on a row. I suggest you use a `TRIGGER` on update, which makes the update fail if date_invoiced is `NOT NULL`. Unless username is 'superman'.
I think that you can code what you want following this example.

```
DELIMITER ||

CREATE TRIGGER upd_lock
    BEFORE UPDATE
    ON table_name
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.date_invoiced IS NOT NULL AND USER() NOT LIKE '\'superman\'@%' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = '[upd_lock] - Record is locked';
    END IF;
END;

||
DELIMITER ;
```